# Missing Stripe Connect Custom Account Information for Node.js

Tags: node.js, swift, stripe-payments

Currently working on server side info for Stripe connect and I'm having issues figuring out the correct parameters for creating a stripe connect account. I'm stuck on tax_id (ein) at the moment. Can someone please give me the correct abbreviation for this any others I may be missing on Node.js.

For example when it came to the name of the business Stripes API just say "name". Yet I kept getting the error 'Received unknown parameters: name'. But after some help looking online I saw that the correct way was to write out 'business_name' even through this was no where in the Stripe API.

here is my code: Hope this helps guide some people in the right direction as well (:

```
app.post('/newConnectCompanyAcct', (req, res) => {
// Creating New Connect Account...

     //User
     var company = req.body.business_name
     var ein = req.body.business_tax_id
     var first = req.body.first_name
     var last = req.body.last_name
     var email = req.body.email
     var phone = req.body.phone
     var birthDay = req.body.birthDay
     var birthMonth = req.body.birthMonth
     var birthYear = req.body.birthYear
     var ssn = req.body.personal_id_number
     var time = req.body.Time
     var ip = req.body.iP

     //Acct Type
     var type = req.body.type

     //Address
     var line1 = req.body.line1
     var line2 = req.body.line2
     var zipcode = req.body.postal_code
     var city = req.body.city
     var state = req.body.state
     var lastFour = req.body.lastFour


     console.log('the email ' + email);
     console.log('the phone ' + phone);


    stripe.accounts.create({
            type: "custom",
            country: 'US',
            requested_capabilities: ['card_payments','transfers'],
            product_description: "example description",
            mcc: "7299",
            business_name: company,
            tax_id: ein,
            legal_entity: {
              address: {
                  line1: line1,
                  line2: line2,
                  postal_code: zipcode,
                  city: city,
                  state: state
              },
              // relationship: {
              //   representative: true,
              //   title: "Manager"
              // },
              dob: {
                  day: birthDay,
                  month: birthMonth,
                  year: birthYear
              },
              first_name: first,
              last_name: last,
              type: type,
              personal_phone_number: phone,
              personal_email: email,
              ssn_last_4: lastFour,
              personal_id_number: ssn,
              personal_address: {
                  line1: line1,
                  line2: line2,
                  postal_code: zipcode,
                  city: city,
                  state: state
              }
            },
            tos_acceptance: {
                  date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                  ip: ip
            }
    }).then((accounts) => {
          console.log(accounts)
          // Send customerId -> Save this for later use
          return res.status(200).send(accounts.id)
    }).catch((error) => {
           console.log('error while creating new account' + error)
           return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: error }))
    });

});
```

Comment: The reason that the API reference differs is that you appear to be using an older version of the Stripe API. While Stripe maintains backwards compatibility with all older versions, there have been a lot of changes to the Accounts API which included moving the business_name and other details into the `company` hash.

Comment: @taintedzodiac How would that look? and how do update the api?

Comment: You'd want to either [upgrade your account's API version](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#how-can-i-upgrade-my-api) to make all calls use the latest version, or you can [use a specific version on each API call](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning) if you prefer a more metered approach.

Comment: @taintedzodiac do you have any idea how I can fix my current syntax without updating the api. Its seems like it going to be a lot of new info learn and I'm currently pressed for time. I just need to get the business name, ein and job title for the manager.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Never mind I figured it put based off the links you sent me. It all makes sense now. Thank you.